# Count percent of all peaple who got specific email

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to count and make percent  of people who use specific email. Like from all people use `@gmail.com`, 55% people. I got just one table, in what table date is like `Artor.Makaka@gmail.com` or `Artony.Nenuoku@yahoo.com`

I can't found solution to make it. I try `like` operator in `Count` function, but don't work it for me... got the error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  email, count(email Like '%_@gmail.com') * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over(), count(email Like 
 '%_@yahoo.com') * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over()
FROM people 
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I need to get something like what https://www.part.lt/img/866951b6da637a118364f85d1baee3b2526.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can benefit from `cte` structure like below as an alternative solution:

```
;with cte as (
  SELECT  sum(case when email Like '%@gmail.com' then 1 else 0 end) as GmailUsers,
          sum(case when email Like '%@yahoo.com' then 1 else 0 end) as YahooUsers,
          count(*) AllUsers
  FROM people 
)
select GmailUsers,YahooUsers, 
       (cast(GmailUsers as float)/cast(AllUsers as float))*100.0 as GmailUsersPercentage,
       (cast(YahooUsers as float)/cast(AllUsers as float))*100.0 as YahooUsersPercentage
from cte
```

Comment: an order by in a CTE?

Comment: @Hogan thanks, nice catch. I don't think we need to use "order by" at all

Comment: From cte, i get error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: @mausasu1234 can u please try again? Should be working now

Comment: something not corrent in '%@gmail.com' then 1 else 0) i got error now here Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @mausasu1234 ok, can u please try again now?

Comment: now is working GmailUsers and YahooUsers but dont work at precent, i got just zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203200/discussion-between-mausasu1234-and-eray-balkanli).

Comment: @mausasu1234 seems like we'll need to use casting. please try now.

Answer (score 0):

`count(email Like '%_@gmail.com')` doesn't make any sense, it's just a wayawrd boolean expression.

I *suspect* what you want is

```
 SELECT email,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN email Like '%_@gmail.com' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / count(email) over(), --Count perform a COUNT in a SUM
        COUNT(CASE WHEN email Like '%_@yahoo.com' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(email) over()
 FROM people 
 GROUP BY email;
```

I can't, however, test to ensure this works.

Comment: images aren't helpful, @mausasu1234 . if you want to supply sample data and expected results, do it as `text` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 (SUM(CASE WHEN email Like '%_@gmail.com' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(*)) * 100
FROM people
```

Comment: I just got zero :/

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it just be easy enough to do 3 queries `select count(*) from email where email like '%_@domain.com%`

```sql
declare @total int = select count(*) from people
SELECT (count(*) / @total) * 100 FROM people where email like '%_@gmail.com'
SELECT (count(*) / @total) * 100 FROM people where email like '%_@yahoo.com'
SELECT (count(*) / @total) * 100 FROM people where email like '%_@live.com'
```

Comment: declare @total int = select count(*) from people dont work for me writing  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: ah forgot you can't do that it just needs to be split up from declare statement and initialize. I'll edit it

Comment: nvm too long ago to edit change the first line to this `declare @total int = (select count(*) from people)`

Answer (score 0):

with the following code, you don't need to add email domain manually to your script. It will fetch automatically and save your time:

```
create table #tmp (email varchar(100))

insert into #tmp 
(email)
values
('Artor.Makaka@gmail.com'),
('Artor.Mak@gmail.com'),
('Artor.Mak@yandex.com'),
('Artor.Makya@yandex.com'),
('Artor.Makya@hotmail.com'),
('Artakaka@gmail.com');

declare @total int
select @total=count(1) from #tmp

select
SUBSTRING(email,PATINDEX('%@%',email),LEN(email)) emailDomain
,Count(SUBSTRING(email,PATINDEX('%@%',email),LEN(email))) numberofuser
,Count(SUBSTRING(email,PATINDEX('%@%',email),LEN(email)))/(1.*@total) percentage
from #tmp
group by SUBSTRING(email,PATINDEX('%@%',email),LEN(email))
```